# Prevent data leak due to file permissions during installation in UNIX

Tags: installation, sh, posix, file-permissions, umask

I install files using standard POSIX utilities `cp`, `install`, `sed`, `sh`.

It is possible to fix any permission with `chmod` / `chown` / `chgrp` but **it is dangerous to temporarily expose sensitive data and fix it later**.

"Standard" way to deal with the problem is to use `install -m MODE -u USER -g GRP`.

What if I need to process file with a "dumb" utility (like `grep` / `sed` / `awk` / `sh` )? How can I prevent data leak from such tools? By using `umask 777`?

I consider following dangerous:

```
base64 -d secret.txt >/etc/app.key
sed -e '/^#.*/d' </etc/default/app.cfg >/etc/app.cfg
```

because file content might be accessible to other users if `umask` is too open. Also I have to "fix" user/group after redirections...

**PS** Seems `install` is not in POSIX... https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html

Also GNU `install` doesn't read from pipe, so following trick is impossible:

```
sed ... < $SRC | install -m MODE -u USER -g GRP - $DEST
```

Some shell allow *process substitution* (`<(cmd)` syntax) or one might create named pipe as workaround...

Comment: this might be one for the sister site https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just a home user here, but I'd use superuser privileges to install an empty file at the destination, perform the necessary chown/chgrp/chmod commands while there is no sensitive data in the file, then write the file as desired. Only users/groups with write access can update the file, and only those with read access can see the contents. If you have a group of, say, 20 files that all need the same permissions (e.g. all 0700 perms, even if owner/group is different), that's where the umask command would be particularly useful, allowing you to use 1 umask invocation instead of 20 chmod invocations

Answer (score 1):

After reading POSIX I see that there is no guaranty for `mkdir`, `cp` and other tools to respect `umask`. Actually `umask` is a process property and is handled by kernel/syscals.

I'd better use non-standard GNU install with `-m MODE` (`-u`, `-g`).

For dumb tools GNU Bash with process substitution would be handy:

```sh
install -m 0700 <(sed ... $SRC) $DST
```

But I'm not sure of FIFO permissions...